# Firefox extension to organise tab groups

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

In Firefox, I often have 80 or more tabs open in 25 or more tab groups. My tabs are nicely organised in the tab bar, but my tab groups are all over the place.

[image: Tabs all over the show]

I try to keep the organised, the same size, in rows and columns alphabetically but it takes up so much time...

Does anyone know of an extension that can organise tab groups for me? Or is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: There was apparently some momentum in 2012 to address the UI problems with panorama, but looks like it's been abandoned again.  I would love to see this implemented: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764224

Answer (score 2):

when I encountered your problem I decided to use the plugin [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) to manage my tabs. It's to me the best tab manager of firefox. But it's not exactly what you search

So I found this [TabGroups Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabgroups-manager/) which options seems to do what you want. It's could be your solution.

Or that: [Tab Kit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-kit/) : Tab grouping, vertical tab tree, multi-rows, and various tweaks for power users.

Or that: [TabGroups Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabgroups-menu/) Access panorama from a menu or a toolbar button. If you find that the panorama view in firefox is too slow after opening many tabs, you can alternatively switch tab using this menu.

Comment: Yeah, they're not quite what I'm looking for. I like Firefox's tabgroup manager, but I just want to arrange them into rows and columns. Something like Windows' desktop's "auto arrange icons"...

Answer (score 1):

This is on the radar of the Panorama team, but has not been implemented, either directly in Panorama or in a third-party add-on.

I am experiencing the same problem - I typically have 80+ tabs in ~10 groups, which are nicely (manually) arranged so as to prevent the tabs being stacked. Creating a new group gets really fiddly though, as if I put it over the top of (or even near) an existing group it causes the groups to 'auto arrange', usually very badly, undoing all my careful arrangement.

Auto-arrange is something that would be theoretically possible to create as an add-on. This problem, and the idea of an add-on, sees some discussion here: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/KXfG1Vf7txHcp79i1AaU

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Tab Group Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-group-bar/) and [Tab Groups Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-groups-helper/) add-ons.